# How to run Command Prompt from a C++ program

Tags: c++, api, cmd

I'm hoping to write a simple program in C++ that would allow me to run a Command Prompt through a C++ program, i.e. input commands in the C++ program are sent to the Command Prompt (CMD terminal will be hidden) and messages returned in the Command Prompt terminal are displayed in the C++ program.

I know about running .bat scripts but something more dynamic would be much better.

I'm just wondering if there are any C++ API's or libraries that allow us to perform this so I can research into them.

Comment: You could use the `system` function that is built into C++. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

Comment: Wow, so this does exactly that. Thanks a lot! Didn't know it was so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a built-in string class type object firstly. Now, in an infinite loop, ask the user to input something *in the beginning of each iteration*. Execute the commands with the help of `system()` (put `.c_str()` member function after the identifier of the string which will convert them and represent as a char array because the system function hasn't any overloaded function that uses String class).